# Wordpress ACF does not retrieve field info

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, advanced-custom-fields

I was wondering what is the problem that I am having with the information retrieval from the back-end. (never had such problem before)

**I have made an index.php which consists of get_template_part() partials.
To be**

```
<?php get_header(); ?>


    <?php get_template_part( 'partials/index', 'slider' );
         get_template_part( 'partials/index', 'services' );
             get_template_part( 'partials/index', 'work' ); 
                get_template_part( 'partials/index', 'testimonials' ); 
                     get_template_part( 'partials/index', 'recent' ); 
                         get_template_part( 'partials/index', 'technologies' ); 
                             get_template_part( 'partials/index', 'contact' ); ?>


        <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

All those template parts have their own html+php included. 
It retrieves all the HTML from those partials, but the info that stand on ACF fields, its not retrieved.

**index-services.php in "partials" folder example:**

```
<section id="services">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
            <div class="title">

                <h1 class="section-heading text-uppercase">
                    <?php  the_field('service_section_title'); ?>
                </h1>

                <p class="text-faded">
                    <?php  the_field('service_section_description'); ?>
                </p>

                <div class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
                    <a href="<?php  the_field('service_section_button_link'); ?>">Learn more</a>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Adding all the link of index-services.php (With repeater field)

**http://pastebin.com/xXwBf8uG**

[Image of retrieved HTML of get_template_part()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFx0b.png)

And the problem is, that none of those the_field() functions are retrieving the information from the back-end.

I have set field in back-end to be shown in Page as Index (And they are shown, filled)

Am I having a problem with query loops?

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the post ID: `<?php the_field($field_name, $post_id); ?>`

If you are outside the loop, that could be the problem.

Comment: maybe you have time to explain it?

Comment: <?php  global $wp_query;
echo $wp_query->post->ID; ?> 
You suggest this?

Comment: sorry, forgot to quote the code. So see my answer above with code

Comment: In index-services.php I guess you are looping through some posts right? Take those post IDs

Comment: I got the "77138" (probably the post_id). But nothing else is being show :/

Comment: Ok, try that. So for example `<?php  the_field( 'service_section_title', 77138 ); ?>
Better is not to hard code the post ID of course.

Comment: And it retrieved nothing... Blank. Have never seen this issue before.

Comment: Oh wait: these are repeater fields? Try this: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_sub_field/

Answer (score 0):

The ACF `the_field()` function works inside of loop. It uses `$post->ID` to get information attached with any specific post or page.
Try passing the post id like `the_field('FIELD_NAME', $post->ID);` or in case of repeaters you need to pass post id in repeater loop:

```
if ( have_rows('FIELD_NAME', $post-ID) ){
    while ( have_rows('FIELD_NAME', $post->ID) ): the_row();
        the_sub_field('SUB_FIELD_NAME'); // No need to add post ID here
    endwhile;
}
```

I guess that will solve your problem.

Comment: My problem was that I used the_field() inside the loop, should have used the_sub_field()

Comment: @MartinČiurlionis yes. Just skipped my mind. I've edited the answer. It might help someone else.